# R radarchart rendering issues (no plot shown)

Tags: r, d3.js, radar-chart

I would like to use to render a radarplot using the radarchart library in R. Everthing worked fine until I tried to change the colorscheme of the plot.

```
radarchart:::colourMatrix(diag(255, nrow=3))
```

After that, the radarchart is not plotted anymore.

What I did so far, was to remove (an re-install) radarchart and its dependencies htmltools and htmlwidgets.

=====

In Chrome the following errors are reported in the console:

> Chart.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null
>   to object
>       at Function.keys ()
>       at Object.o.each (Chart.min.js:12)
>       at Chart.min.js:14
>       at Object.o.each (Chart.min.js:12)
>       at a.determineDataLimits (Chart.min.js:14)
>       at a.update (Chart.min.js:13)
>       at Chart.min.js:12
>       at Object.o.each (Chart.min.js:12)
>       at Object.update (Chart.min.js:12)
>       at t.Controller.updateLayout (Chart.min.js:11) Chart.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_data' of undefined
>       at t.Controller.update (Chart.min.js:11)
>       at t.Controller.resize (Chart.min.js:11)
>       at Chart.min.js:11
>       at Chart.min.js:12

Before I removed both htmltools and htmlwidgets, there was another error, something like render.... not defined (but I don't remember precisely).

Comment: We need more info and reproducible example

Comment: I found out part of the problem/mistake. In my attempts to solving the color problem I put quotation marks instead of the variable names in the plot function. Eg, chartJSRadar("skills") instead of chartJSRadar(skills). 

The color problem--using the function stated above persists--however. Once I try to change the color scheme the plot is no longer shown.